# How to add opacity only to the text leaving the image without any opacity in the same element?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add some opacity to the text in the element. But I dont want to apply any opacity to the image in the same element. Is there any way to do this ?
What I want to achieve is to show a spinner gif on the element with the text opacity.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

h1 {
opacity:0.1;
background: url('spinner.gif') no-repeat center !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading.this is text test</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think using another `<div>` is the wrong solution - please don't spread the div-itis virus. The correct way is to use `rgba` colors.

```
h1 {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1); /* white with 0.1 opacity */
    background: url(...) ...;
}
```

And by the way, please also refrain from using `!important`. The "narcissistic css property pattern" is probably the worst thing you can adopt in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a div and set the div to have the background image, and then make the h2 have the opacity,

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/ch6fbqs7/

```
<div id="text">
<h1>This is a heading.this is text test</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#text {
    background: url('http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/news2/Picture-of-the-Day-Real-Life-Simba-and-Mufasa-Caught-on-Camera-in-Tanzania-392687-2.jpg') no-repeat center !important;  
}

#text h1 {
opacity:0.1;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the heading h1 into a div, and then use the background image you want as the div background, then you are free to set the h1 text opacity. See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.someClass {
background: url('spinner.gif') no-repeat center !important;
}
.someClass h1 {
opacity:0.1;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="someClass">
    <h1>This is a heading.this is text test</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with using a wrapper div to hold the background image (as suggested already) if that's what works best for your image, but based on the idea of a simple loading spinner, it may be the cleanest to just use RGBA color for the text:

https://jsfiddle.net/kyjp4vf9/

Fiddle uses a color background, but it will have the same result with an image.  `opacity` and `rgba` have similar browser support, most notably IE9 works for both and IE8 usually doesn't (it has partial support for opacity, if you don't mind using an `-ms-filter` rule.